# whirlpool/ hop stand duration and temps

Tags: hops, techniques, all-grain, late-addition

I've been using hop stands for all of my beers, but they all have been slightly different.  I was wondering what you guys would recommend in terms of when to add the hops (at what temperature) and for how long. I add a minimal bittering charge at 30 or 15 min depending, then add the rest of the hops during the hop stand.  Usually the hops stand is about 20 min, then I turn on the wort chiller and run it until its cold enough to pitch (66-68F typically).  If you guys have any recommendations, I'd appreciate it. Thanks! Also, I do dry hop after fermentation is complete and let that stand for 4-5 days.

Comment: You might check this question / answer, which discusses the timing of flame-out hop additions: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7169/should-the-late-addition-portion-of-a-recipe-be-altered-based-on-immersion-coun

Answer (score 1):

We did an experiment about this at www.experimentalbrew.com for our Experimental Brewing podcast.  Here is a link to the experiment parameters and results....https://www.experimentalbrew.com/experiments/hop-whirlpool-does-steeping-lower-temperature-improve-final-hop-character

Comment: Great link, Think some of these podcasts will find their way into my phone :)